# Docker registery show images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I installed docker registry according to this [Document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04)
now i have this images :

```
registry            latest              9d0c4eabab4d        2 weeks ago         33.2 MB
nginx               1.9                 c8c29d842c09        12 months ago       183 MB
```

and this containers :

```
faa2aece26bd        nginx:1.9           "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   18 hours ago        Up 16 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   dockerregistry_nginx_1
e4cbee0e296e        registry:latest     "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   18 hours ago        Up 16 minutes       127.0.0.1:5000->5000/tcp       dockerregistry_registry_1
```

now docker engines can login , push and pull images without any problems .
but in docker registry server `docker images` command do not show images stored (push by docker engine) in docker-registry container !
how can fix this problem ?

Comment: Why is that a problem and why do you expect that to work?

Comment: my problem is : `docker images` command do not show images .

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is some confusion here. `docker images` command only shows images which have been previously pulled and are cached locally. What you have installed and configured is a private docker registry. This means that you can use this registry to push and pull images.

If you would like to see all the images available in your registry you need to query the [registry API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/). Also you can install one of the various registry GUIs like [kwk/docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend) which will allow you to view the images using your web browser.